# On mount, check if Enter/Return key is being pressed and use that information in onBlur event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button that can be highlighted with Tab, where pressing Enter when the button is highlighted creates an Input field.  That input field is then focused.

The input field has a keyUp event and if the key is Enter/Return, blur the field (and save the info that was put into the field).

The issue:

- Tab to select Button
- Keydown Enter/Return to create Input field
- Input field is now focused
- Keyup Enter/Return
- Input becomes blurred

What I need is to know if the enter/return key was pressed on mount and stop the Keyup event from firing if that is true.

```
export default function EditableLabel({
  active,
  value: valueProp,
  variant,
  ...rest
}) {
  const [returnPressedOnMount, setReturnPressedOnMount] = useState(false);
  let isReturnPressed = false;

  // Only set this listener on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keypress', isReturnKey, false);
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  function isReturnKey(event) {
    console.log(event.keyCode);
    if (!returnPressedOnMount && event.keyCode === 13) {
      console.log('In the return key func');
      setReturnPressedOnMount(true);
      isReturnPressed=true;
      console.log(isReturnPressed)
    }
    document.removeEventListener('keypress', isReturnKey, false);
  }

  function handleBlur(evt) {
    setIsEditing(false);
    rest.onChange && rest.onChange({ target: { value } });
    rest.onBlur && rest.onBlur(evt);
  }

  function handleKeyUp(evt) {
    console.log(returnPressedOnMount);
    console.log(isReturnPressed);
    if (evt.key === 'Enter') {
      if (!returnPressedOnMount) {
        const target = evt.target;
        setTimeout(() => target.blur(), 0);
      } else {
        setReturnPressedOnMount(false);
      }
    }
    rest.onKeyUp && rest.onKeyUp(evt);
  }

  return (
    <Input .../>
  );
}
```

This code works if I hold the Enter/Return key down for a long time, but if someone presses the key normally (just tap the key, not holding it down) the State/Variable do not update in time for the onKeyUp.

How do I get the knowledge of the Return key being pressed on Mount to the onKeyUp function?

Comment: Why not just use an `onchange` event on your input and a `onclick` event on your button, like 99.999999999999% of the rest of the world and save your 50 lines of javascript for something actually useful?

Comment: @gforce301 like most code I work on, I didn't write this component :) but thank you for the suggestion